# Does mongoengine support for Transactions API in MongoDB?

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, mongoengine

Does mongoengine support for Transactions API in MongoDB?  I am trying to access the mongodb  using python script. I was able to successfully do crud operation using mongoengine library. But I need to extend that program so that I would able to access db data through the Transactions API. I use ubuntu OS and python for development. Can anybody help me with simple example how to do this? many thanks....
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/

Answer (score 1):

Although the underlying driver (pymongo) supports transactions, MongoEngine does not support that yet, so you can't make use of pymongo's Session object with MongoEngine Documents instances.

Related ticket from the project https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/issues/2248

Answer (score 0):

MongoEngine is an ODM. Transactions are implemented by the driver. An ODM may provide additional transaction-related syntax/functionality but that would be on top of the driver.

According to http://docs.mongoengine.org/faq.html MongoEngine uses pymongo. pymongo is a driver and implements transactions. So, you need to figure out how to access the driver's session object from MongoEngine and then use that session object to execute transactions as described in https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/client_session.html.